# What is the proper way to handle module level arrays in a VBA class?

Tags: arrays, vba, class, properties

What is the proper way to handle a module level array in a VBA class?

I use `Property Let` and `Property Get` for other variables, but I haven't figured out how to pass arrays to and from Properties.

Updated. This code works thanks to Mark Nold.

```
Option Explicit

Private mstrTestArray() As String

Public Property Get TestArray() As String()
    TestArray = mstrTestArray
End Property
Public Property Let TestArray(ByRef strTestArray() As String)
    mstrTestArray = strTestArray
End Property
Public Property Get TestArrayValue(d1 As Long, d2 As Long) As String
    TestArrayValue = mstrTestArray(d1, d2)
End Property
Public Property Let TestArrayValue(d1 As Long, d2 As Long, strValue As String)
    strTestArray(d1, d2) = strValue
End Property

Sub DoTest()

    Dim strTestArray() As String
    ReDim strTestArray(2, 1) As String

    strTestArray(0, 0) = "a": strTestArray(0, 1) = "one"
    strTestArray(1, 0) = "b": strTestArray(1, 1) = "two"
    strTestArray(2, 0) = "c": strTestArray(2, 1) = "three"

    TestArray = strTestArray

    Debug.Print TestArrayValue(UBound(TestArray, 1), UBound(TestArray, 2))

End Sub
```

The following does not work. This top part is a method in the above class:

```
Sub LetArrayFromReference(ByRef strTestArray() As String)
    TestArray = strTestArray
End Sub
```

This part is a procedure that calls the class:

```
Sub DoTest()

    Dim strTestArray() As String
    ReDim strTestArray(2, 1) As String
    Dim objTestClass As New TestClass

    strTestArray(0, 0) = "a": strTestArray(0, 1) = "one"
    strTestArray(1, 0) = "b": strTestArray(1, 1) = "two"
    strTestArray(2, 0) = "c": strTestArray(2, 1) = "three"

    objTestClass.LetArrayFromReference strTestArray

    Debug.Print objTestClass.TestArrayValue(UBound(objTestClass.TestArray, 1) _
    , UBound(objTestClass.TestArray, 2))

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below might give you some clues to help. First define a class called `TestClass`.

```
Option Explicit

Private strTestArray() As String

Public Property Get TestArrayValue(d1 As Long, d2 As Long) As String
    TestArrayValue = strTestArray(d1, d2)
End Property

Public Property Let TestArrayValue(d1 As Long, d2 As Long, sValue As String)
    strTestArray(d1, d2) = sValue
End Property


Sub DoTest()

    Dim myTestArray() As String
    ReDim myTestArray(3, 1) As String

    myTestArray(0, 0) = "a": myTestArray(0, 1) = "one"
    myTestArray(1, 0) = "b": myTestArray(1, 1) = "two"
    myTestArray(2, 0) = "c": myTestArray(2, 1) = "three"

    strTestArray = myTestArray
    Me.TestArrayValue(3, 1) = "Hello"


    Debug.Print strTestArray(2, 1)
    Debug.Print Me.TestArrayValue(1, 1)
    Debug.Print Me.TestArrayValue(3, 1)

End Sub
```

Then in a code module or a worksheet create a sub called MyTest();

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyTest()
  Dim t As New TestClass
  t.DoTest  

  Debug.Print "The value at 1,1 is; " & t.TestArrayValue(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Within the class you can update `strTestArray()` or `Me.TestArrayValue`. I'll let you create a Get and set for TestArray. I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to do..so if you have any questions leave a comment and update your OP :)

Comment: That's the tip I was looking for. You basically have to have two sets of Let/Get for an array property. One for the value and one for the array. I also had a typo in my code. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Mark, I added some code (after "The following does not work") to my question. Can you please comment on why it is not possible to set the array property from a method parameter? Is it because doing so tries to create a ByRef from a ByRef? Thanks!